# Cannot find elements in Appium Inspector

Tags: javascript, ios, appium

I am trying to set up some automated testing for iOS using appium. As far as I know, I have got the app running correctly. It finds my compiled app and is able to run the app in the inspector.

Where I am running into an issue is that although I can click on buttons, textfields, etc, in the inspector, I can't actually pass any text into those text fields.

Also, when I run the test, I keep getting the error that you cannot find element (any element) based on the parameters being used.

Ultimately, I want to test on a real device, but until I can comfortably reach the elements in question, I don't want to move in that direction. I'm using Javascript for this by the way.

```
browser.init(desired).then(function() {
    return browser
        .execute("mobile: tap", { "tapCount": 1, "touchCount": 1, "duration": 0.5, "x": 250, "y": 466 })
        .sleep(10000)
        .elementByXPath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIATextField[1]").sendKeys("email@email.com")
        .elementByXPath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIASecureTextField[1]").sendKeys("Password")
        .elementByXPath("//UIAApplication[1]/UIAWindow[1]/UIAButton[1]").click()
        .fin(function() {
            // return browser.quit();
        });
}).done();
```

Comment: Does it miss the elements all the time? I too faced the same problem. Is that UI control having name? It always works with name if not with appium inspector generated Xpath.

Comment: Yes, when using the XPATH with a UIATextField and the sendKeys method.  I have been able to make it work by hitting each individual key on the keyboard with the .click() method instead, but man, what a lousy hack.